# how to change the URL from a GET-variable to imaginary directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, directory

All the links in the website are a get-variable. The user opens always the index.php and gives different get-variables, which defines the different content.

**Example:**
The home page is example.com/?p=1
The contact page is example.com/?p=7

Now I want the URLs to look like example.com/contact. And because the number of pages is not static I can't create a directory for every page.

Probably I need a way to import the content of my index.php (example.com?p=3) to a path, which doesn't exist (example.com/new-path).

I've heard there is a way to solve that using the .htaccess file.

Comment: I found a duplicate of this question with a helpful answer :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19668686/redirect-without-changing-url?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

I'm not .htaccess / mod_rewrite expert, but just found this one may be useful for you. Note that you'll have to provide an entry for each page you are redirecting as the system will not know the relationships between the numbers and the pages by itself. You may have to fiddle around with it a bit to try and remove `index.php`.

```
# Original URL: 
# http://www.example.com/index.php?p=1

# Desired destination URL:
# http://www.example.com/path-to-new-location/

# .htaccess syntax:

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} p=1
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /path-to-new-location/? [L,R=301]
# Redirect URLs with query parameters (files placed in subdirectory)
```

Note, `#` is a sign for comments, anything on that line (*in gray*) will be ignored, it's sole purpose is to provide you information / comments on the code.

Source (line 52-63): [Common .htaccess Redirects - Gist](https://gist.github.com/ScottPhillips/1721489)

Comment: Thats a good way to redirect to the new location. But I need a folder called "path-to-new-location"... basically I need a way to change the URL without changing the content